# Application protocol-based port forwarding/redirection

Tags: linux, iptables, port, tcp, redirection

I need to split traffic on port 80 between HTTP and non-HTTP, and internally forward HTTP traffic to a port nginx will listen to, and non-HTTP traffic to port 22.

Does anyone know of a piece of software that would do just that -- "application-based port forwarding" ?

Thanks for any ideas !

Comment: rapht, welcome to SF - but did you take even a few seconds to read the help documents you had to click through to post this question?  [We make it fairly clear](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) that requests for software recommendations are off-topic for the site.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mean I wanted to buy anything -- actually I'm not wanting to throw money at the problem, just to find the proper type of software to answer that specific need.

Comment: That is exactly what we mean by "*software recommendation*" - a pointer to a piece of software.

Comment: Try searching for "port multiplexer" instead. There's a number of applications that do that for ssh.

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for -- just didn't know the name.

Answer (score 1):

You need 'Policy-Based Routing' - look for this in your routing solution.